# GRUB 2 boot error: "out of memory"

Tags: linux, boot, fedora, grub2

I just installed a [SAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Attached_SCSI)/[SATA 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#SATA_revision_3.0_(6_Gbit/s,_600_MB/s,_Serial_ATA-600)) controller (IBM M1015) and now I am unable to boot the system (GRUB 2 bootloader).

The last boot messages I see are:

```
Verifying DMI Pool Data .................
.
out of memory
Aborted. Press any key to exit...
```

I booted a Fedora 20 live CD (with all current updates installed), mounted my main LVM sysimage, and tried to reinstall GRUB 2:

```
mkdir /x
mount /dev/fedora/root /x
grub2-install --root-directory=/x /dev/sda
```

which finishes with reported success.

But at boot it still fails with the before mentioned "out of memory error.

I also tried to add `vmalloc=256m` to the GRUB default cmd-line and updated GRUB 2 with `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2` (of course booting the system without the controller installed).

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Do you have a swap partition created on the drive?

Comment: I'm currently having this problem on an Ubuntu 16.04 machine. Did you ever figure this out? It's definitely the M1015.

Comment: No I never figured it out and abandoned it in the end.. at the time I used a Gigabyte X52 (or sort of) mainboard and all resources I found (as far as I can remember) pointed towards bad BIOS implementation and that specific boards from ASUS with same chipset but different BIOS were reported to work.. the M1015 is now running in an Intel server board and is rocking solid since..

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me your problem is totally unrelated to GRUB, and I get my clue from the message:

```
 Verifying DMI pool data
```

DMI (Desktop Management Interface) is a layer of abstraction between system
components and the software that manages them. The System Management BIOS (SMBIOS) is an extension of the Basic Input Output System (BIOS) that formulates and delivers this information to the operating system. The pool data is the information. In short, when the BIOS is "Verifying DMI pool data" it is verifying the table of data it sends to the operating system.

The fact that this message appeared immediately after you changed the SAS/SATA 3 controller is another clue to the true origin of the problem.

Possible options include:

1. reverting to the old controller.
2. checking the existence of a partition table of a type (MS-DOS/UEFI) appropriate to your boot option (Legacy/UEFI).
3. Set the motherboard CMOS Setup to Auto for the drive type, **after** having disconnected the drive.
4. Enable "Reset Configuration Data" ("Force Update ESCD" in some CMOS Setups) in
   the motherboard CMOS Setup PNP/PCI configuration. A reboot will automatically disabled it the next time around.
5. Clear the CMOS, which may have been corrupted by your change of controller.

Comment: I did the suggested and the only thing changed was that the "Verifying DMI Pool Data ................." now ends with "Update success", then the same "out of memory" message appears and the system halts.

Answer (score 0):

**Check for File System Errors**

It could also be file system errors on the root partition of the drive.

I had this yesterday with

```
# grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

So rebooted with a bootable USB memory stick loaded with "System Rescue Disk"
http://www.system-rescue-cd.org/

and ran Gparted to do a disk and file check.
Menu > System > Gparted

Errors were found and corrected in / partition.

Rebooted
Reran "grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg"
and no errors found.